# How to bind array fields in r2dbc mysql?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, google-cloud-spanner, r2dbc, r2dbc-mysql

Im trying to bind array fields in spanner using java reactive programming and using r2dbc spi binds
https://r2dbc.io/spec/0.8.0.RELEASE/api/io/r2dbc/spi/Statement.html

I'm encountering this exception
`com.google.cloud.spanner.r2dbc.BindingFailureException: Can't find a binder for type: class [Ljava.lang.String`

We can use binds for array fields in spanner as mentioned here [How to bind to IN parameters in Cloud Spanner Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43587138/how-to-bind-to-in-parameters-in-cloud-spanner-java-api)

But this bind works only spanner statements but not for r2dbc

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Cloud Spanner? If Cloud Spanner, support for arrays was [added after the last release](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-spanner-r2dbc/pull/495), and at this point will be released for SPI v0.9 and 1.0.

Comment: @ElenaFelder Despite updating both spanner r2dbc and r2dbc-spi to their latest versions, Im still noticing the same error.
```com.google.cloud.spanner.r2dbc.BindingFailureException: Can't find a binder for type: class io.r2dbc.spi.Parameters$InParameter``` Im trying to bind them like this ```.bind(arrayField, Parameters.in(R2dbcType.COLLECTION,
                        arrayValues[]))``` Do you know if spanner really supports it?

Comment: Cloud Spanner supports it, but the Cloud Spanner R2DBC support has not been released yet.

Comment: @ElenaFelder so is there no way to bind arrays without using cloud spanner ?

Comment: @ElenaFelder and also is it possible to integrate spanner and r2dbc-spi

Comment: The way to integrate Cloud Spanner and R2DBC is https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-spanner-r2dbc . However, we have not released support for array binding yet, so it is not currently possible.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by " so is there no way to bind arrays without using cloud spanner" -- do you mean you are choosing between different databases?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by " so is there no way to bind arrays without using cloud spanner" -- do you mean you are choosing between different databases?  No I mean unless we use native cloud spi, is there no way for us to bind arrays currently?

Comment: If you mean R2DBC SPI, it requires a database-specific driver. The latest release of Cloud Spanner R2DBC driver does not have this functionality yet, so yes, currently there is no way.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Appreciate your time

Comment: You could use Cloud Spanner client library's async API to bind arrays, but it's complex.

Answer (score -1):

[cloud-spanner-r2dbc@v1.2.0](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-spanner-r2dbc/releases/tag/v1.2.0) added support for binding arrays and lists to Spanner native arrays.